# What is "Maximum Client Connections" on Remote Access (DirectAccess) dashboard

Tags: direct-access

I was hoping someone might be able to enlighten me regarding the value of 'Maximum client connections' on the Remote Access Dashboard. Is this a hard limit or simply the most concurrent connections to date?

If it is a hard limit where do I go about changing it?

I've tried searching for the answer in the help files and on the web but am having a hard time getting any results.

[image: Remote Access Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most concurrent connections reached.

Comment: Or most concurrent connections to a single DA sever in a DA farm if you have more than one DA server.[snip from my Remote Access console](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tksma.jpg)